# git - not able to rebase and squash my commits

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have three commits on my repo, I am trying to combine this commits. however, while trying to do that it shows following error.

**Error:**
in valid upstream 'HEAD~3'

**command used**

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rebase+initial+commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git rebase -i --root` as "Initial commit" is your first commit.